# C# Get date value of week day by name in a Date Range

Tags: c#, datetime

I have `string[] WeekDayNames` that represents the array of week day names (like 'Monday', 'Wednesday')

I need Date for all day names in WeekDayNames for a specific Date Range.
Example: Wednesday between 19 Nov 2013 and 28 Nov 2013 has days: 20.11.2013 and 27.11.2013

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to Google, spend a lot of time already

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy Don't tell us *that* you tried something, *show us what you tried, explain what you researched, and explain why it didn't work* for you.

Comment: I made a research in google. thats all. i did not find any example that match or be approx like my needs. So that i use stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i would convert your strings to real `DayOfWeek`s ...

```
string[] WeekDayNames = new[] { "Monday","Wednesday" };
DayOfWeek[] days = WeekDayNames
    .Select(s => (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), s))
    .ToArray();
DateTime start = new DateTime(2013, 11, 19);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2013, 11, 28);
```

... then you can use this LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> range = Enumerable.Range(0, (end - start).Days + 1)
    .Select(d => start.AddDays(d))
    .Where(dt => days.Contains(dt.DayOfWeek));
```

Comment: Works like a magic! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a simple loop like:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 11, 19);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 11, 28);

List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
while (startDate <= endDate)
{
    if (startDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        list.Add(startDate);
    }
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Its better if you use `DayOfWeek` enum instead of storing string values.

If you want to get dates for each element of your string array `WeekDayNames` then:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013, 11, 19);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2013, 11, 28);
string[] WeekDayNames = new[] { "Wednesday" };
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
while (startDate <= endDate)
{
    if (WeekDayNames.Any(r=> r==  startDate.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
    {
        list.Add(startDate);
    }
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I accepted an answer of @Tim due to more 'beautiful' implementation